# Determine Linear independence from a linear combination of original vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a bit confused on this question it seems really straightforward but it says its work 10 marks, can someone help me improve this answer?

Let V be a vector space over a field F not of characteristic 2. and let $u, v, w$
be three distinct vectors in V . Prove that $\{u, v, w\}$ is linearly independent if
and only if $\{u + v, u + w, v + w\}$ is linearly independent.

Let $a= \{u, v, w\}$ and $b = \{u + v, u + w, v + w\}$ Assume a is LI then we can write,
$$M =\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 0  \\
 0& 1& 1  \\
1 & 0 & 1  
\end{array}\right]$$

Its clear that R3-R1+R2 then $\frac{R3}{2}$, followed by R2-R3 and then R1-R2 gives us the identity matrix. So if a is LI then so is b. Now if we assume b is LI then the above process tell us that this is the same as saying u,v,w are LI which is precisely a.

EDIT: This may be a simpler way of putting it $b=Ma$ by above we know that M is invertable so $a=M^{-1}b $  by the first line we know that if a is LI then so is B and by the second line we know if b is LI then so is a.